# Software for Mac or app that lets you draw function graphs

Tags: graphing-functions

Does anyone know if there's a software or app that lets you draw functions and then write out its equations automatically? I know that GeoGebra does it but all the way around. I've been searching and I only found one which is for Windows.

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific. Are you asking for software that will perform regressions? That said, I think this question is off topic anyway.

Comment: I don't know what regression is (my mother tongue isn't English). I want to be able to draw (or by "curve fitting") piecewise-defined functions, for example and that later on the program would give me the equations of that.

Comment: roughly speaking [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) is the process of fitting a curve to data. Many statistical packages, and even Microsoft Excel can do various forms of regression analysis.

Comment: @jgon no, I don't think that has to do with anything that I want to do. I want to be able to make these types of functions https://image.slidesharecdn.com/2-130925143628-phpapp02/95/writing-piecewise-functions-word-problems-4-638.jpg?cb=1380119816

Comment: Are you trying to plot piecewise functions?

Comment: @jgon I think that is what is called. Not graph it knowing the equations but doing the opposite thing.

Comment: If you have the equations and want to graph it, that's called plotting. If you have the graph (or some points on it) and want to find its equation, that's regression.

Comment: Also, the answers in the question you linked are examples of regression software. Also they aren't for windows, they're online. (At least one of them)

Comment: @jgon oh i get it now! Yes, I want a program that can perform regressions

Comment: @jgon yes, the curvefit one but it only visualizes the positive part of the x and y coordinates

Answer (score 1):

What you want is just impossible. This is the reason why you can't find any piece of software.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292750/draw-a-line-output-equation check this out